# SonarQube 5.3 migration with data

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

we have currently **SonarQube** v.4.5.1 running on postgresql database.

We would like to migrate into new version 5.3 which will be running on NEW SERVER (with new postgresql DB).

So I have followed migration tutorial http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading (downloaded into new server new SonarQube 5.3 application, migrated configuration, migrated plugins).

**Then I have created DB dump of old sonarqube 4.5.1 postgresql database and loaded it into new database on new server**.

When I have started new SonarQube i see error - **SonarQuebe is trying to create new table projects but he fail, table is already existing (from imported DB dump).**

How can I migrate data to new instance of SonarQube ?

Does old data need to be somehow 'processed' to be used with new version of SonarQube?

Comment: You're trying to do two things at the same time: 1 - upgrading SonarQube and its DB (SonarQube topic), and 2 - moving DB from one server to another (DB topic). Focus on SonarQube upgrade first (no dump/load of DB, just a backup), and share logs of the error you're getting.

Comment: Thx. So i have installed new sonar 5.3 on clear DB - everything works fine (plugins migrated). Is possible to move DB from one server to this new one ? (DB topic)

Comment: Nope. You should not start on a clear DB. The [upgrade process](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) is about pointing a new SonarQube server to the same DB as used previously (by a server which is now stopped).

Comment: Thank you ! After i have NEW SonarQube pointed to existing DB, i opened /setup page and after backup SonarQube 5.3 have migrated database without any errors. Now i will just make backup of migrated DB - create dump - and move it to new DB server. Thank you one more !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SonarQube upgrade process uses the same database between previous and new SonarQube version. Moving the database from one DB server to another is another process, unrelated to SonarQube.

Point your new SonarQube to the database used by the previous version (`sonar.jdbc.url`), and browse to `/setup`. SonarQube will then take care of 'upgrading' your SonarQube data.